# Batch File Passing Variable for ip

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to make a batch file that when used will set the ip. To which I think I achieved. The downfall is that I want it to be able to pass a variable when I use it. For example SETIP 37. would plug the variable 37 into the ip.

Below is my code

```
rem Network Settings for IP

netsh interface ip set address name = "Local Area Connection" source = static addr = 192.168.10.(target for variable) mask = 255.255.255.0

netsh interface ip set address name = "Local Area Connection" gateway = 192.168.10.1 gwmetric = 1

netsh interface ip set dns name = "Local Area Connection" source = static addr = 192.168.10.1

netsh interface ip show config

pause
```

Comment: What have you tried? I would think passing `"192.168.10.$var$"` would work...

Comment: It would be `%var%`, not `$var$`. But yeah, you can absolutely simply use a variable.

Answer (score 0):

You could easily create a command line tool out of this. Save the script below as `SetupIP.bat` and then make a call to it (from an elevated prompt) like so:

```
SetupIP 132
```

The above would setup the network with the IP address of 192.168.10.132.

Script source which is your commands above accepting a command line parameter for final part of the IP address:

```
@ECHO OFF
REM Usage:
REM    SetupIP {'D' IP address component}

REM Note that this command requires elevated rights, so it must be run as an administrator.

REM Validate a value was entered.
IF "%~1"=="" (
    ECHO No IP value was provided.
    ECHO Enter only the last component of the IP address to configure.
    GOTO :EOF
)

rem Network Settings for IP

netsh interface ip set address name = "Local Area Connection" source = static addr = 192.168.10.%~1 mask = 255.255.255.0

netsh interface ip set address name = "Local Area Connection" gateway = 192.168.10.1 gwmetric = 1

netsh interface ip set dns name = "Local Area Connection" source = static addr = 192.168.10.1

netsh interface ip show config
```